# Show that $A' \mapsto Hom_R(A, A')$ is a functor on $R$-modules to abelian groups.

Tags: abstract-algebra, category-theory, modules

For a fixed $R$-module $A$, show that $A' \mapsto Hom_R(A, A')$ yields a functor on $R$-modules to abelian groups.

**My start:** As given, let the functor $F$ send objects $A' \mapsto Hom_R(A, A')$ and morphisms $ Hom_R(B, C) \mapsto hom(Hom_R(A,B), Hom_R(A, C))$, where $A, A', B,$ and $C$ are objects in the category of $R$-modules. (Linear maps between $R$-modules are sent to group homomorphisms between $Hom$ groups.) I will call the original category $\mathscr{C}$ and the new category $\mathscr{D}.$

A composition of linear maps $s \circ t \in hom(\mathscr{C})$ is sent to $F(s \circ t) \in hom(\mathscr{D})$...

I'm stuck here. I know that I'm supposed to show that $F(s \circ t)$ = $F(s) \circ F(t).$ Do I instantiate arbitrary $a, b \in A$ and compute $(s\circ t)(a + b)$ and then apply $F$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you have to do is show that a module map $\alpha: B \rightarrow C$ induces a well-defined map $\alpha_*: \mathrm{Hom}(A,B) \to \mathrm{Hom}(A,C)$ via $\alpha_*(f) = \alpha \circ f$.  Show that $\alpha \circ f$ is a module map, then that $\alpha_*$ is a group hom.  Then the functorial axioms follow immediately.

Comment: How did you come up with the map $\alpha_*(f) = \alpha \circ f$?

Comment: Two reasons:  (a) I'm old (that's code for "experienced") and (b) it's the only natural way to build such a map given the one you were handed from $B$ to $C$.

Comment: Okay, so when doing these proofs, try to construct a canonical map and then show it satisfies axioms?

Comment: Yes.  A good part of this is that the whole process should be "natural."